# Widget settings disappear after refreshing page

Tags: widgets, options

I am developing a plugin that displays your average Google My Business rating in a widget. Everything works fine, except when I close the widgets page and return to it later (or do a plain refresh) I cannot edit the widget settings anymore i.e. they dissappear. The only options that remain are remove and save.

When widget is added it looks normal. Settings are viewable (sorry, I can't add image, because I am only allowed to add two links, due to my lack of reputation. :P)

And after I close and return later or refresh the page it looks like this:

[image: When I close or refresh the page it looks like this.]

I have been digging through my code, but I haven't been able to locate the problem. The funny thing is, if I setup the plugin it functions fine. The settings are saved and on the front end it shows the widget as it is supposed to. Only after a page refresh or revisit the settings disappear and the settings are lost. What did I miss?

The widgets consists of three files, which are included in the main file.

You can view the code of all files on github: https://github.com/Dan0sz/google-my-business-reviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the include_once within form() to require solved the bug.